# Not able to create xpt file (Sas8) label greater than 40

Tags: sas

TS-140 Record layout not working.
Below is the header section for variables greater than 40.
HEADER RECORD*******LABELV8 HEADER RECORD!!!!!!!nnnnn
where nnnnn is the number of variables for which long labels will be.

Can we get any sample xpt (sas8) file (Atleast one label is greater than 40).

Comment: What is the programming question you have? What is the code you are running? What are your issues?

Comment: I am creating xpt file using c#. There are no issues with that. There are latest update to include the labels more than 40 characters in (Sas8) file. Question is regarding Sas8 file which should able to open in Sas Viewer.

Comment: What viewer? If you want to use XPORT files that use advanced features supported by the %loc2xpt and %xpt2loc macros then you need to use SAS itself to convert them into datasets.

Comment: We are using Sas Universal Viewer. Can we able to see Sas label whose length is greater than 40 in Sas universal viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the File Open menu of SAS Universal Viewer it definitely says V5 transport files.  The V5 format supports only the limits that existed in SAS version 5.  So 8 character names, 40 character labels, max length of 200 for character variables.

[image]

But it looks like it does support the longer values.  At least when using Version 1.42 .

[image]
[image]

Code to make example:

```
data v8;
  attrib var1 label=
'This label is so long that it will have more than 40 characters';
  input (var1 var2 ThisNameIsMoreThan8Chars) (:$1.);
cards;
1 2 3
4 5 6
;

%loc2xpt(libref=work,memlist=V8,filespec=xpt,format=auto);
```

Resulting file:

```
305   data _null_;
306    infile xpt lrecl=80 recfm=f;
307    input;
308    list;
309   run;

NOTE: The infile XPT is:
      Filename=...,
      File Size (bytes)=1440

RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0
1         HEADER RECORD*******LIBV8   HEADER RECORD!!!!!!!000000000000000000000000000000

2   CHAR  SAS     SAS     SASLIB  9.1     LIN X64.                        07JUN21:11:11:51
    ZONE  54522222545222225454442232322222444253302222222222222222222222223345433333333333
    NUMR  3130000031300000313C92009E100000C9E0864000000000000000000000000007A5E21A11A11A51
3         07JUN21:11:11:51
4         HEADER RECORD*******MEMBV8  HEADER RECORD!!!!!!!000000000000000001600000000140
5         HEADER RECORD*******DSCPTV8 HEADER RECORD!!!!!!!000000000000000000000000000000

6   CHAR  SAS     V8                              SASDATA 9.1     LIN X64.07JUN21:11:11:51
    ZONE  54522222532222222222222222222222222222225454454232322222444253303345433333333333
    NUMR  3130000068000000000000000000000000000000313414109E100000C9E0864007A5E21A11A11A51
7         07JUN21:11:11:51
8         HEADER RECORD*******NAMSTV8 HEADER RECORD!!!!!!!000000000300000000000000000000

9   CHAR  ........var1    This label is so long that it will have         ........
    ZONE  00000000767322225667266666267276266662766726727666266762222222220000000022222222
    NUMR  020001016121000048930C125C09303F0CFE704814094079CC081650000000000000000000000000

10  CHAR  ........var1                            .?..........................var2
    ZONE  00000000767322222222222222222222222222220300000000000000000000000000767322222222
    NUMR  00000000612100000000000000000000000000000F01010000000000000002000102612200000000

11  CHAR                                              ........        ........var2
    ZONE  22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222000000002222222200000000767322222222
    NUMR  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001612200000000

12  CHAR                      ............................ThisName
    ZONE  22222222222222222222000000000000000000000000000056674666222222222222222222222222
    NUMR  0000000000000000000001010100000000000000020001034893E1D5000000000000000000000000

13  CHAR                          ........        ........ThisNameIsMoreThan8Chars
    ZONE  22222222222222222222222200000000222222220000000056674666474676566634667722222222
    NUMR  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024893E1D593DF25481E83812300000000

14  CHAR  ....................
    ZONE  00000000000000000000222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
    NUMR  01010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
15        HEADER RECORD*******LABELV8 HEADER RECORD!!!!!!!1

16  CHAR  .....?var1This label is so long that it will have more than 40 characters
    ZONE  00000376735667266666267276266662766726727666266762667627666233266676676772222222
    NUMR  01040F612148930C125C09303F0CFE704814094079CC081650DF250481E040038121345230000000
17        HEADER RECORD*******OBSV8   HEADER RECORD!!!!!!!              2
18        123456
NOTE: 18 records were read from the infile XPT.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks. Will you able to send above sample file. I was looking for a working example.

Comment: You can recreate it from the hexcodes in the log I have added.

Comment: I am truly blank about Sas, I was opening the file only using Sas universal viewer and i will check the rules by editing in notepad++. So truly i dont know how to create that xpt file from above hexa codes. But I understood the file structure.

Comment: If you have the coding skills to make a C program to generate an XPT file you should be able to convert the lines of text in the SAS log above into a binary file of 1,440 bytes.  18 blocks of 80 bytes each.

Comment: Thanks. Can we have chinese characters in Sas Label (xpt file). Do we have any limitations for the the 2 or more byte characters.

Comment: I would assume they would work, Try it.  Count the number of BYTES, not characters, when filling the binary fields in the transport file.  Does the new V8/V9 member header have a place for setting the encoding?